# what is Java best practice to handle enum's

Tags: java

hi I know Java for a long time and recently I have been diving deep to the Java world.
As an experienced c# developer I find it odd to use Java enum's.
For example if I show on console items such as :

```
public enum AdminOpertionFirstlayer 
{MANAGE_SUPPLY,
 MANAGE_CUSTOMERS_SERVICE,
 ORDERS_MANAGEMENT,
 REPORTING_OPRATIONES}
```

I find it hard to write them down to the user , cause I have to define new varible

```
*AdminOpertionFirstlayer []adminOpertionFirstlayerArr =
     AdminOpertionFirstlayer.values();
```

in order to achieve this :

```
for (int i = 0; i < adminOpertionFirstlayerArr.length; i++) {
    String s = String.format("%d. %s",
                             i+1,
                             adminOpertionFirstlayerArr[i].toString());
    Screen.print(s);
}

AdminOpertionFirstlayer chosen= adminOpertionFirstlayerArr 
                                [(Integer.parseInt(dataIn.readLine()))-1];
```

But I feel it's a bad practice to declare on *

1. Is there a best practice (enum extension is one ... ) ?
2. Is there TryParse available or every time I parse I should try and catch  ?

thank you

**EDIT**

does doing this is understandable and readable ?

```
  public enum MainMenuOptiones{

    ADMIN {public void secondLayerMenu(){
      Main.AdminSecondLayerMenu();}},

    CUSTOMER{public void secondLayerMenu(){
       Main.customerSecondLayerMenu();}},

    EXIT{public void secondLayerMenu(){
        System.exit(1);}},

    UNAPPLICABLE{public void secondLayerMenu(){
        Screen.printToScreen("chice doesnt exist  try again");}};

    abstract public void secondLayerMenu();
}
```

the phrphes is instead of using all the switch mechanism
 I can use

```
 enumInstance.secondLayerMenu();
```

Comment: Don't start with an uppercase for variable names. It is confusing as names beginning with an uppercase are normally class names. See [Code Conventions for the Java Programming Language](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconv-138413.html).

Answer (score 5):

You could use Java's enhanced for loop (and the ordinal value for the enum)

```
for (AdminOperatorFirstLayer operator : AdminOperatorFirstLayer.values()) {
    String s = String.format("%d. %s", operator.ordinal(), operator);
    Screen.print(s);
}
```

Then you can use the ordinal value to recreate the enum:

```
AdminOperatorFirstLayer chosen = 
    AdminOperatorFirstLayer.values()[(Integer.parseInt(dataIn.readLine()))];
```

Or you could use the name:

```
for (AdminOperatorFirstLayer operator : AdminOperatorFirstLayer.values()) {
    String s = String.format("%s. %s", operator.name(), operator);
    Screen.print(s);
}
```

Then you can use valueOf value to recreate the enum:

```
AdminOperatorFirstLayer chosen = 
    AdminOperatorFirstLayer.valueOf(dataIn.readLine()];
```

Comment: and how should I parse it back ? it's no solution ...
and i doesnt exist in this context ..

Comment: You don't have to do the intermediate step of declaring the array. `AdminOperatorFirstLayer.values()[Integer.parseInt(dataIn.readLine())-1]` will work, you will need to surround with try/catch or otherwise validate the user's input.  You can also display the enums using the for loop Michael included.

Comment: but it's not relvant ' and does not keep 1.order is not gartered using foreach 2.i doesn't exist in this context  but in order to keep peace :)  I would change it ...

Answer (score 1):

The [`Enum<E>`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Enum.html) class is the base for all enums in Java.

There's no need to declare a variable with values, use an enhanced for loop to print them out if you want the users to read your source code.

Generally you want to print out a localised string rather than the name of the enum in the source.

There isn't an equivalent to `TryParse`, instead use `AdminOpertionFirstlayer.valueOf(AdminOpertionFirstlayer.class, string)` and catch the IllegalArgumentException.

Comment: can you say more about 1, I would like to see an example or link and then I would understand what you mean

Comment: Click on `Enum<E>` in the answer and you go to the Java docs with all the methods common to all  enums in Java.

Comment: I am having an hard time understanding you it's no c# therefore Enum has just valueof and class as his prop and methods can you be more specific ?

Comment: @yoav.str any enum has all the public methods of Enum - compareTo(), equals(), getDeclaringClass(), hashCode(), name(), ordinal(), and the static valueOf. Or you can step through the values() and compare ordinal or string value.